# Timezone conversion and daylight saving

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timezone, dst

We have a scheduler application. Using this application an user can schedule a task to run at 8 AM PT daily for the next 30 days. We convert the time to UTC and store it in the databse as we have users from various time zones. We use the following function to convert the time to UTC:

```
public static DateTime ToAccountLocalTime(this DateTime dt)
{
    return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dt, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("user time zone"));
}
```

Now if the user scheduled a task to run at 8 AM PT daily for the next 30 days on 1st Nov 2012 then in the database 30 entries are made for each of the 30 days with time set to 4 PM UTC (as returned by the above method).

The problem occurred on Nov 4th when daylight saving ended. The task started running at 7 AM instead of 8 AM as the scheduler service runs all times based on UTC.

To solve this we need the above method to return 4 PM UTC for dates from 1st Nov to 3rd Nov and 3 PM UTC for dates after 4th Nov. What changes should I make to achieve this?

Comment: Just have a look at the MSDN Library article for ConvertTimeFromUtc.  Note how it uses IsDaylightSavingTime().

Comment: You should consider that daylight saving isn't applied the same way around the globe. I found [this link](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/When_is_Daylight_Saving_Time) listing some of the way daylight saving is applied. Storing your time in UTC will standardize time but I don't think you can't standardize daylight saving.

Comment: Consider using Noda Time: https://code.google.com/p/noda-time

Comment: @HansPassant I am not able to find the article. Can you provide a link?

Comment: @Francois I am aware of this, hence I want to know what is the correct way to fix the issue

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.converttimefromutc.aspx

Comment: @achinth Since you are storing the time as UTC in a database, am I correct in assuming that the scheduler does not know the local timezone of the user that scheduled the job?

Comment: @HansPassant thanks. Last time I went to this link and searched for IsDaylightSavingTime() it returned zero results. Strange!

Comment: @cadrell0 scheduler does not know the local timezone of the user

Comment: @achinth Can you tell us what your current schedule table looks like?

Answer (score 0):

If the local time is what is important, I would store the local time + timezone and convert it to UTC when you need UTC.

Then you store 8AM PT, and it will convert to 3 or 4 PM UTC depending on whether or not it is currently DST.

The problem you will run into is depending on your database, it may not support time zones.  I would probably store the string you pass into `FindSystemTimeZoneById`.  If you wanted to get fancy, you could make a table that lists all of those with an identity column and store the Id.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the conversion for each of the 30 days, so call `ToUtc` (or whatever the opposite of the routine you've pasted in the question is called) for each of `localDate.AddDays(n)`, `n`=`1`..`30`, and store those results.

If `ToUtc` is defined similar to:

```
return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dt, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("user time zone"));
```

it should cater for DST at the time specified. (Be careful of exceptions for ambiguous or invalid times.)